# Jersey - Injection Resolution using a custom Provider/Resolver

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, hk2

I have the following controller

```
@Path(value="/api/v2/")
public class BookController() {

@Inject
private BookService bookService;


public void setBookService(BookService service) {
this.bookService = service;

@GET
@Path(value="/books/{bookId})
@Produces(value = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getAResponse(@Context HttpServletRequest request, @Context HttpServletResponse response, @PathParameter(value="bookId") String bookId) {
// DO SOMETHING WITH BOOKSERVICE
}

}
```

NOw, this `BookService` is instantiated and managed by a service provider. So I have written an InjectionResolver as follows:

```
@Provider
public class ApiInjectionProvider implements InjectionResolver<BookService>{

    @Override
    public Object resolve(Injectee injectee, ServiceHandle<?> root) {
        if (injectee.getInjecteeClass() != null) {
            return ServiceFactory.getInstance().getTheService(getRole(injectee.getClass()));
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isConstructorParameterIndicator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMethodParameterIndicator() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

    private static String getRole(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        try {
            return (String) serviceClass.getField("FQNAME").get(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't get " + serviceClass.getSimpleName() + ".ROLE", e);
        }
    }    

}
```

As a base servlet, I am using a simple extension of jersey's `ServletContainer` where I check my internal tokens etc.

My web.xml (relevant config)

```
<servlet-class>my.internal.AppServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>
        my.web.controllers,
        my.web.providers,
        com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json
    </param-value>
</init-param>
```

After starting web server, I am trying to hit the URL directly with my test key etc. I can confirm that I can reach the servlet, but the forwarding fails with the following error.

```
Caused by: org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at SystemInjecteeImpl(requiredType=BookService,parent=BookService,qualifiers={},position=-1,optional=false,self=false,unqualified=null,314359437)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ThreeThirtyResolver.resolve(ThreeThirtyResolver.java:74)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolve(ClazzCreator.java:214)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:237)
        ... 62 more
```

I am not sure where the issue is. I have the package scanning and my classes are the right package for servlet init scans. I am using Jersey dependencies as follows:

```
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-client:jar:1.19.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-multipart:jar:1.19.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.18:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:jar:2.24:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:jar:2.22.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:jar:2.22.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:jar:2.22.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.bundles.repackaged:jersey-guava:jar:2.22.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-jaxb:jar:2.22.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:jar:2.22.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:jar:2.22.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.swagger:swagger-jersey2-jaxrs:jar:1.5.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:jar:2.27:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.glassfish.jersey.ext:jersey-entity-filtering:jar:2.27:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.glassfish.jersey.inject:jersey-hk2:jar:2.27:compile
```

I can reach my controller if I hardcode the service. I have tried that. So it seems that the injection is failig.

Could someone please help ?

Comment: This seems more like you want to use an implementation of Factory<BookService> rather than an InjectionResolver.  Basically you just want the implementation of provide to, you know, "provide" the BookService (and the dispose can remove it when it goes out of context).

Comment: @jwells131313          would you kindly share an example. I don't have the Jersey source code, so couldn't see an implementation of internal items

Comment: I'm a little busy but will post an example, but in the meantime this is the javadoc for factories: https://javaee.github.io/hk2/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/Factory.html.  In your binder/resource you can register factories and the provide method is called to create instances.  You can even inject https://javaee.github.io/hk2/apidocs/org/glassfish/hk2/api/InstantiationService.html to find out more about the caller (which your original code seems to do)

Comment: Also, the `InjectionResolver<T>` should have an annotation as the type argument: `@param <T> This must be the class of the injection annotation that this resolver will handle`